# Multivariable function's limit $\frac{y^3-x^3}{x-y}$

Tags: limits, functions

Find limit: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{y^3-x^3}{x-y}$. How to find that. Should i look for two subsequences or what? Do not get this.

Comment: *Hint:* Factor the numerator, $y^3 - x^3 = (y-x)(\cdots)$.

Comment: why not just $(y-x)$ without $-$?

Comment: Because then you're left with the term (.......) after cancellation and you're left with a high school algebra problem, Krowskir. : )

Comment: nevertheless i know what to do know, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^3-x^3 = (y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)$  implies that $\frac{y^3-x^3}{x-y}=-(y^2+xy+x^2)$ whenever $x\ne y$.

Comment: If x =y, then the limit's even easier.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The ratio $\frac{y^3-x^3}{x-y}$ is undefined when $x=y$, whereas the limit as $x \to y$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the limit in this way:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}-\frac{(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)}{y-x}=-3$$